# How to generate WHERE condition based on parameter values which are not blank/null in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure where I am performing search operation, the procedure takes 10 input parameters and returns rows found for those parameters.

I am using the `LIKE` search operator, but my problem is there are possibilities that only few parameters are passed with values, the rest can be blank or null. I want to exclude the blank/null parameter values from my query's `WHERE` condition, please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

SP

Comment: Does it have to use LIKE command? IF you are querying on text like this better to use FullText Search IMO. I would also suggest you use parameterized queries from C# , will be more optimal than dynamic query

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from YourTable
where (@Param1 is null or Field1 like @Param1)
  and (@Param2 is null or Field2 like @Param2)
```

You can use **any** condition instead of `like`

Answer (score 0):

`select *
from Table
where isnull(@Field1,Field1) = Field1
and isnull(@Field2,Field2) = Field2`

Using the same technique, you can test for blank before doing the select part of your query and convert it to null before the select (it would then cover your blank and null cases)